# Java rest framework with programmable dispatcher?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, restlet

I'm searching a java rest framework or JAX-RS implementation that allows me to configure the dispatcher at runtime through an API. In JAX-RS it is only possible to do the configuration with @Path and @HttpMethod annotations or by effectively building your own dispatcher in a sub-resource.

I'm searching for:

```
dispatcher.addResource("/my/{path}", Resource.class) or
dispatcher.addResource("/2nd/path", resourceHandlerFactory)
```

Comment: I've got the information via mail that Jersey 2.0 might include this: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-842

Comment: you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing in JAX-RS for dynamic resource specification as you've found.  Apache Wink has another alternative to Restlet called DynamicResource http://incubator.apache.org/wink/1.1/html/5.1%20Registration%20and%20Configuration.html. I'd be quite interested in why you need dynamic resources as I had similar requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I don't _need_ dynamic resources. I just observed, that it is illogic to couple the resource method to the location of the resource. - It does not permit reuse of the resource method at another location.
I'm writing my bachelor thesis about this, see the subchapter on dispatcher: https://github.com/thkoch2001/bachelor-thesis

Comment: Exactly, that's why Restlet API's annotated resources don't allow fixing the location/path. This should indeed be an orthogonal aspect even though frequently a resource is only attached to one URI/path.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/). It provides runtime dispatch functionality through its [Router](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Router.html) class. See http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/326-restlet.html for an example.